# The "register" class function (how to declare)

Tags: python, add-on

The [documentation](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.register_class) on `bpy.utils.register_class` states:

> If the class has a register class method it will be called before registration.

How should this method be declared? What arguments will it be given?

Answer (score 7):

A class method takes at least one argument - the class itself. Here, `register` (and its counterpart, `unregsiter`) do not take anything else, so you must declare them this way:

```
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        pass
```

You have a good example of their usage in Cycles' `propertie.py` file:

```
class CyclesRenderSettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    @classmethod
    def register(cls):
        bpy.types.Scene.cycles = PointerProperty(
                name="Cycles Render Settings",
                description="Cycles render settings",
                type=cls,
                )
        cls.device = EnumProperty(
                name="Device",
                description="Device to use for rendering",
                items=enum_devices,
                default='CPU',
                )
        # ... and so on adding properties to cls

    @classmethod
    def unregister(cls):
        del bpy.types.Scene.cycles
```

That way, you can embed the definition of your propertygroup and handle its container’s creation and deletion inside the class, instead of having to create/delete `bpy.types.Scene.cycles` in the global (un)register funcs.

Comment: The current version (https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/intern/cycles/blender/addon/properties.py) does NOT longer use the second variant (cls.device)